# Simplify a circle into square with SF

Tags: r, simplify, sf

I want to obtain a square from a circle using simplification function in sf.

This is my circle:

[image]

With this code, I obtain a rhombus

`plot(st_simplify(st_geometry(sfdf),dTolerance = 1000))`

[image]

How can I obtain a square? in QGIS I manage to obtain it using *SnapToGrid* option in simplification process.

Comment: I doubt you'll ever get a square output with an ellipse input.

Comment: Would an envelope/minimum bounding rectangle do for you?

Comment: sure, a rectangle is a good option too

Comment: If you have a centre point and a radius that defines your circle then getting the four points of an axis-aligned internal square, is basic trigonometry. Do you have radius and centre coordinate for these circles or just the spatial data object (which is only actually an approximation to a circle)?

Answer (score 5):

`st_simplify` function uses a maximum distance difference algorithm similar to the one used in the Douglas-Peucker algorithm and this algorithm preserves the first point of the shape. Therefore, to obtain a square from a circle using simplification function, the first point of the circle has to be located in direction 45, 135, 225 or 315 degree. In your circle, I guess, direction must be 0, 90, 180 or 270 degree.

Circles below were simplified in the same way, but results are different because of location of the first point.

[image]
[image]

Comment: How could do it in R?

Comment: `st_simplify` is an R function...

Answer (score 2):

One option that has worked for my purpose is to use `st_make_grid` with `n = 1`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

# Make a point
centroid <- tibble(geometry = list(st_point(c(1, 1))))

# Turn it into a circle
circle <- centroid %>% st_buffer(3000)

# Turn the circle into a square
square <- circle %>% st_make_grid(n = 1)

# Plot
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = square) +
  geom_sf(data = circle)
```

[image: plot]